# Logging possibilities in a JRE Extension

Tags: java, jvm

We have developed a custom Crypto provider that has to be installed in JRE as a extension. I am looking different possibilities for debug and trace from this provider. I looked at JCE/JSSE code, they are simply using System.out wrapped in a Debug class. Using Log4j/Log4j2 (they will be loaded at Extension classloader) seems can cause problems to other applications with Log4J running on same JVM. Want to offer both Console and File logging options. Please give some advice with best possible logging strategy??

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use java inbuilt **java.util.logging** apis
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/logger.html